# Change gravatar type to "monsterid" for meta only

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, gravatar

Come on, let's have some fun!

[image]

vs

[image]

Do I need to say more ?

---

Apparently I do!

If a user has a custom avatar, such as me, then nothing will change.

If a user doesn't have a custom avatar then an unique one will be displayed based on the md5 of the user's email. But, there are [several styles you can choose from](http://blog.gravatar.com/2008/04/22/identicons-monsterids-and-wavatars-oh-my/). The one we use is called `identicon`; it's the most professional of all the ones available. But there are more themes, such as `monsterid` (see example above).

They as well are for all intent and purposes unique, different for each email. Let's play around with the hash and get more examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you saying you don't know how to change your email address on Meta?

Comment: I'm talking about the default avatars. Sure, I can change mine and fake the default one posted above, but then everyone's else will still be ugly. EDIT: Oh, maybe you don't know, it's a parameter in the URL gravatar. If the user doesn't have one set, you can choose between several default "themes". The one currently used by us is "identicon", the one I proposed is "monsterid", there are more. See http://blog.gravatar.com/2008/04/22/identicons-monsterids-and-wavatars-oh-my/

Comment: No, he wants to change the mechanism that is used to generate images for people without Gravatars from identicon to monsterid: http://www.splitbrain.org/projects/monsterid

Comment: You didn't mention about changing everyone else's. Looks like you needed to say more.

Comment: Mysteriously changing everyone's avatar would be fun for April 1. Just think of the mayhem if this was done on SO as well as meta...

Comment: But then someone needs to write a MonsterId that creates Unicorns instead.

Comment: @Michael Stum: so YOU'RE responsible for that horrible idea...

Comment: @quack: For the record, I do credit him in the very first centence of the announcement of the project you're referring to.

Comment: @balpha: true dat.  i didn't notice before, but i give you credit for crediting your sources.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

That's a Greasemonkey script even I can "write":

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           monstify
// @namespace      stackoverflow
// @description    Use monsterid instead of identicon
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://serverfault.com/*
// @include        http://superuser.com/*
// @include        http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @author         Benjamin Dumke
// ==/UserScript==

/* most of this code is stolen^H^H^H^H^H^Hadapted from Kip
   Robinson's accept rate details script at
   http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/62156 */

(function() {

  //boilerplate greasemonkey to wait until jQuery is defined...
  function GM_wait()
  {
    if(typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined')
      window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100);
    else
      unsafeWindow.jQuery(function() { letsJQuery(unsafeWindow.jQuery); });
  }
  GM_wait();

  function letsJQuery($)
  {
  $("img").each(function(){
     $(this).attr("src", $(this).attr("src").replace(/d=identicon/, "d=monsterid"));
  });
 }
})();
```

This does the replacing on *all* the Trilogy Sites, but you know how to change it to your needs.

Possible improvements:

- only replace gravatar images that are really user images
- do it without jquery so you can do it earlier (so the original images don't appear briefly)
- make the monsters prettier -- [the Dood](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37260/change-gravatar-type-to-monsterid-for-meta-only/37275#37275) isn't totally wrong
- …

Feel free to refine.

Comment: ITYM `stolen^H^H^H^H^H^Hadapted`.

Comment: @Sinan: I guess you're right.

Comment: Ugh. Replace the "GM_wait" function with an "addEventListener" call.

Answer (score 38):

MonsterIds are really, really ugly.

Comment: what :( -1, you're ugly!

Comment: monsterids are ugly, but wavatars have a similar whimsical style while being much more attractive: http://www.shamusyoung.com/twentysidedtale/?p=1462

Comment: Personally, I find the monsterid's much prettier than the identicons, but then again, des goûts et des couleurs on ne discute pas, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: not only that, they are totally inappropriate for a serious/professional website as SO is.

Comment: @Stefano: maybe you missed the "meta only" part

Comment: @Jeff - i *know!!*  how cool is that!

Answer (score 18):

Unicorns are *waaaay* better than monsters!

Answer (score 13):

Go for [Unicorns](http://unicornify.appspot.com/). Definitely.

Comment: You're aware that this very post is what started the whole unicornify story, right? :)

Comment: @balpha: It did? I never knew that.

Comment: @George Note the highest-voted comment under the question

Comment: @Balpha: No, I didn't. Huh!

Answer (score 6):

I know this is not an answer, but it completes a circle:

[image: unicornified original post]

(I hate those monsterids, anyway)

Answer (score 3):

They look much better in this page: http://scott.sherrillmix.com/blog/blogger/wp_monsterid/

Comment: Oh those are much nicer!

Comment: I got a really weird one: http://scott.sherrillmix.com/blog/wp-content/plugins/monsterid/e174bef324654e0.png

Answer (score 3):

Identicons, ATTACK!

Oups... wrong movie... sorry.

Answer (score 2):

I make fix?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Monstrify
// @namespace      http://stackexchange.com
// @description    Use monsterid instead of identicon
// @include        http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @include        http://serverfault.com/*
// @include        http://superuser.com/*
// @include        http://meta.stackoverflow.com/*
// @author         Hello71
// @changelog      Doesn't require jQuery, only replaces user avatars, fixed namespace, changed author, better name.
// ==/UserScript==
(function () {
    var replace = function (imgs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
            var img = imgs[i];
            img.href = img.href.replace("d=identicon", "d=monsterid");
        }
    };
    replace(document.querySelector("#user-avatar > img");
    replace(document.querySelectorAll("#user-gravatar32 > a > img");
}());
```